# Flink Streaming API: how send element to multiple (but not all) partitions?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink 1.5 has `broadcast()` and `partitionCustom()` methods, which allow to send an element either to *all* or *just one* partition.

Is it possible to send element to two or more partitions, but not to all of them?

Is it going to be supported in the API?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is no direct support for such scenario. However you can implement it pretty easilly with `flatMap` function by emitting multiple results for a single input element.

E.g.

```
stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Object, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void flatMap(Object value, Collector<Tuple2<Object, Object>> out) throws Exception {
        out.collect(Tuple2.of(/*key1*/, value));
        out.collect(Tuple2.of(/*key2*/, value));
        out.collect(Tuple2.of(/*key3*/, value));
    }
}).partitionCustom(new Partitioner<Object>() {
    @Override
    public int partition(Object key, int numPartitions) {
        return /* desired partition */
    }
}, 0);
```